# Redirecting to another action in same controller and passing some data asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I want to redirect to another action in same controller and pass one parameter value. I have this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

}

public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
  if (isFailed)
  {
    // Redirect to Index Action with isFailed parameter so that some message gets displayed on Index page.
  }
 }
```

I read about using `TempData` but my session is read only (for some purpose) thus I if I save data in `TempData` in `SomeAction`, it does not help since `TempData` is empty in `Index` action.

Another thing I tried is using `RedirectToAction("Index","Test", new { param = isFailed})` in `return` statement of `SomeAction`. This works and I can access `param` in `Index` action using `Request.QueryString['param']` but the issue with this is the url now becomes `/AreaName?param=true` where I want it to be `/AreaName/Test/`.

This is my routemap:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "AreaName/{controller}/{action}/{param}",
            new { controller="Test", action = "Index", param=UrlParameter.Optional },
        );
```

I am submitting a form using "post" from MyJS.js to `SomeAction`.

Is there any alternative/workaround method for doing this? In nutshell, I want these three things:

1. Redirect to `Index` action.
2. Pass the value of `param` from `SomeAction` to `Index`.
3. Keep the URL: `http://localhost/AreaName/Test/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index(Datatype param)
{

}
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
if (isFailed) 
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index" , "Home",new{param= value });
}    
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Redirect to `Index` action.

Use `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");`

- Pass the value of param from `SomeAction` to `Index`.

You can use the [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx) object.

> The TempData property value is stored in session state. Any action method that is called after the TempDataDictionary value is set can get values from the object and then process or display them. The value of TempData persists until it is read or until the session times out.

You can do it as below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //you can access TempData here.
}

public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
  if (isFailed)
  {
      TempData["Failure"] = "Oops, Error";  //store to TempData
      return RedirectToAction("Index" , "Home");
  }
  return View();
 }
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) explains it all.

- Keep the URL: `http://localhost/AreaName/Test/`

You can do so by adding a route in your `RouteConfig.cs`

```
context.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "AreaName/Test/",
            new { area = "AreaName" controller="Test", action = "Index"},
        );
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I cannot use TempData because my session state is read only and temp data uses session by default to store data. We can override that behavior but that requires overriding the default provider which is again something I cannot change in my code. For the URL part, I dont want the query parameter to display in url string. How that can be done?

Comment: I think u added that to ur questn after i answered this.

Comment: No, it was mentioned before only.